# JQuery plugin function calling

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to call jquery plugin function from my page, but I fail:(. My code is:

```
var pstps=$('#psteps_simple_horiz_layout').psteps({
        steps_width_percentage: true,
        alter_width_at_viewport: '1300',
        steps_height_equalize: true
    });
    step_num=2;
    pstps.go_to_step(step_num);
```

The plugin is Pine Steps wizard. It's code is:

```
function($) {
$.fn.psteps = function(options) {
    // Build main options before element iteration.
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.psteps.defaults, options);

    // Iterate and transform each matched element.
    var all_elements = this;
    all_elements.each(function(){
        var psteps = $(this);
        psteps.psteps_version = "0.0.1alpha";
        .......................................................
        psteps.go_to_step = function(step_num){
            var last_active_title = psteps.find('.step-title.last-active'),
            .......................................................
        };
        .......................................................
        this.pines_steps = psteps;
    });

    return all_elements;
};
```

When I run my code I get error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is failing on the following line because `go_to_steps` is not a jQuery extension (and the return value from `psteps()` is the original jQuery object:

```
pstps.go_to_step(step_num);
```

You need the instance of the actual plugin. Looking at the plugin code, it connects the instance as a property on the DOM element called `pines_steps`, so you need to get that property as your class instance:

```
var pstps=$('#psteps_simple_horiz_layout').psteps({
    steps_width_percentage: true,
    alter_width_at_viewport: '1300',
    steps_height_equalize: true
})[0].pines_steps;
```

Then you can call

```
pstps.go_to_step(step_num);
```

**Common pattern:**

The usual way plugins are authored is to also accept a function name, as a string, in a first parameter, so they can call methods like this:

```
$('#psteps_simple_horiz_layout').psteps("go_to_step", step_num);
```

*however this plugin is missing the code to do that*